# How to add custom field and display it in admin-new-order.php file in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I am working in **Wordpress** with **WooCommerce** and my client wanted to display a new field under "My Account" page of his customers called "Certification Type".

I have uploaded through a plugin a CSV file with 4000 of his customers and within this plugin there were custom fields (including the "Certification Type") that were added to the database.

My client wanted to display this field within the email he receives every time some of his clients orders something. So basically I have created a child theme and added the admin-new-order.php file.

Inside this file I have added the following code:

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    echo 'Certification Type: ' . $current_user->Certification . "\n";
?>
```

When I tested the code using my admin login, I receive the email and the code works fine and shows me the value that I have in the Certification Type field. When my client tried it he receives the Certification Type: without showing what is in the field of the client who made the order.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?
I am not really good with php so sorry in advance if I am doing something blatantly wrong.

**Update**: I have recently figured out that my client's server is running Windows NT. Does this have to do anything with the issue? I have also installed a plugin to clear the cache but I am still getting the same result. Can someone please point me to the right direction here? What am I missing?

Comment: Hey guys,
I've done some more testing and it seems that if I manually edit the customer's account (by just clicking edit and then update on their profile) the email received from them contains the Certificazion Type filed with its value!
I don't know why this is happening but I can't really go through 4000 customer accounts and edit and update them manually!
Any thoughts? Is it maybe a cache issue?

Answer (score 3):

Well i think a new user field should have been added to wp_usermeta table instead of the wp_users table. The way you are looking with `get_currentuserinfo();` this means that it is added to the users table. But if it was added to the usermeta table then you should have done this.

```
<?php echo get_user_meta($user_id, 'Certification', true);  ?>
```

So first of all you have to confirm which table stores the certification field.

1) is it in the wp_users table or in wp_usermeta table. For this you will have to log into your phpmyadmin or whatever database software you are using, then goto both of these tables and search for a random user for example search for user_id = 57 and see whether the Certification field is inside the users table or is it inside the usermeta table.

Or use a sql query like this to see all the user meta results for a random user id (make sure your db prefix is wp_ or replace it with your db table name)

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = 57', OBJECT );
var_dump($results); die();
```

This is just for debuging and will dump all the usermeta of the user_id 57 in your browser. So you can then use chrome search to search for "Certificate". If you do find it here, then it means that the data is stored in usermeta and you just simply need to run this code to get the certificate. Also there is a difference between "Certificate" and "certificate", so make sure you are asking for the one in the database.

**EDIT: Here is the complete code to use**

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    echo 'Certification Type: ' . get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'Certification', true) . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: yes just replace 57 with the user id 14622 or 14623, and then just paste the results in your question

Comment: Sorry but I accidentally answered before and took my answer down as I wanted to do a bit more of a research. I am currently on my mobile phone so I don't have access to the database at the moment. I will get back to you later when I will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot for your time. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Sure, i hope it helps

Comment: Hi omer,
I did a search in the database and I found out that the Certification field is inside usersmeta table. I also tried your code inside "My Account" page and in fact it showed all the user meta of a certain user and the Certification field was in there.

I then replaced my code with the one you gave me `<?php echo get_user_meta($user_id, 'Certification', true);  ?>` but nothing shows up.

I am sure the field is with written correctly as I copied it from the database.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the $user_id ? If you are still using the get_currentuserinfo function then replace $user_id with $current_user->ID. Checkout my edit for complete code to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I had a typo that's why it wasn't working! Now the code seems to be working alright but I need to wait for a client to make an order before I can check if it's working.

The thing I find weird is that with the code I used before I could see the field correctly in the email I was receiving with my testing orders while the clients email weren't showing at all.

I'll wait for an order and keep you updated.
Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: Hi omer. There was a new order and the custom field is displayed correctly with the order email! Once again I am so thankful for your help!!!

Comment: Glad to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Being that this is not one of the default fields, I personally would write an SQL script which would insert the data for this field for each customer. I am assuming that the date for this custom field is stored in user_meta table so that would be the first play I investigate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but I am not really aware of how to write SQL scripts. I just google all the commands I need to use every time I have to search or change something in my database. However, I am suspecting there is something weird going on in the database as I found out that 960/4000 users didn't have an email address when I imported them. I have now set a custom email for all of them to check if this is what was causing the problem. And yes the data for the field is stored in user_meta table.